# Being told Firebase sign-in provider is disabled when it is enabled

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm doing a pretty basic sign-in using FirebaseUI, just basic HTML and JS. I've currently set up and enabled Google, Apple, and email methods in the Firebase panel and my code (Microsoft isn't enabled yet).

[image: Firebase panel settings]

```
signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    {
        provider: "apple.com",
    },
    {
        provider: "microsoft.com",
        buttonColor: '#0067b8',
        loginHintKey: 'login_hint'
    },
    {
        provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD,
        requireDisplayName: false
    }
],
```

Google sign-in flow works like a charm, but with Apple and even email I get:

[image: Apple sign-in fail] [image: Email sign-in fail]

I do note that in either case, selecting the sign-in method first tries to launch *myapp*.firebaseapp.com/... (in a popup or iframe, depending on FirebaseUI setting) before returning to my sign-in page with that failure message.

Same behaviour on both desktop (Mac/Chrome and Safari) and Android/Chrome.

I assume I'm missing some really obvious step here, particularly with email sign-in, but after fiddling with it for a couple of days I'm at a loss. Does anyone have any pointers to shove me in the right direction?